# Eureka, ZUUL, Docker Compose on bridge network java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I'm running a Zuul service and Eureka service on separate docker containers with minimalistic configurations (both are spring boot projects).

Eureka:

docker-compose.xml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: eureka
    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eurekaserver_app_1:8070/eureka/
    tty: false
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 8070:8070
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM java:8
COPY ./build/libs/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/eureka/
WORKDIR /usr/src/eureka
EXPOSE 8070
CMD ["java","-jar","eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Zuul:

docker-compose.xml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: zuul-service
    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eurekaserver_app_1:8070/eureka/
    tty: false
    ports:
      - 8069:8069
    network_mode: bridge
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM java:8
COPY ./build/libs/zuul-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/item/
WORKDIR /usr/src/item
EXPOSE 8069
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","zuul-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I used the `network ls --no-trunc` Docker command to make sure they are not spinning up a new network:

```
NETWORK ID                                                         NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
ba216f3e01bb168848074a99875666fe382a4eda15daad0c428a8102707ee49f   bridge              bridge              local
a63a8adf0fd162d9b99bdf77bc4a13c0bfcfb8a9aca3c5375e60d5df5c5e305d   host                host                local
2debbe96f8a96fdd8d6da983877609e0bdb7a1df6b25537f35f1608de0739fc7   none                null                local
```

Which seems alright, The problem is that Eureka container starts up properly, however zuul-service isn't when I used `docker-compose up`. It throws:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
app_1  |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
```

I am quite unsure on what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) docamantation says:

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

I suggest you to create one `docker-compose.yaml` file for both applications, properly name them and separate `Dockerfiles` to different folders:

```
version: '2'
services:
  eureka:
    build:
      context: ./eureka/
    image: eureka
    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka:8070/eureka/
    tty: false
    ports:
      - 8070:8070
  zuul:
    build:
      context: ./zuul/
    image: zuul-service
    environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eureka:8070/eureka/
    tty: false
    ports:
      - 8069:8069
```

When containers are up, they will be able to communicate between each other by `eureka:8070` and `zuul:8069` accordingly.

Comment: well i tried that with no luck, then i also tried adding: network_mode: bridge to both the applications within same docker-compose.xml and seperately as well, it brought me to new error i.e.: om.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: eureka: Name or service not known

Comment: @vaibhav It was a typo in my answer. I've corrected `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` environment variable in zuul block.

Comment: Yep i could figure that out, still no luck, i am unsure if this problem is because of some config in zuul/eureka, coz to me everything seems fine from docker perspective

Comment: The problem was: network_mode: bridge once i removed that and used single docker compose for both the containers.. it worked!